# Most frequent real number (not integer) in Numpy along a given axis - is there a fast approach?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assuming that we have an array like:

`x = np.random.randn(4000000, 4)`

and we want to find the most frequent element along `axis=0`.

The rude approach is to build a set of histograms for each dim:
`hist = [np.histogram(x[:, i], bins=200) for i in range(x.shape[-1])]`

Separate frequencies and values into different variables:

`freq, val = (np.array([o[0] for o in hist]).T, np.array([o[1] for o in hist]).T)`

then argmax along frequencies:
`most_freq = np.argmax(freq, axis=0)`

then take diagonal of the values from val (to get only elements with the same indices i=j):
`np.diagonal(val[most_freq])`

which should be around ~`[0., 0.]` here

How to make it faster, for example np.histogram is not very vectorized approach and we have to make it along every axis.

Comment: With floats, you might not have any repeats.  Equality tests with floats are best done within a tolerance (`is_close`).  I guess your histogram bins count as doing that.  A few loops (e.g. 4) on a complex task like `histogram` is quite acceptable in `numpy`.  What you want to avoid is many loops on a simple task.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this will work faster:

```
np.bincount(x).argmax()
```

Comment: Hello stukituk

by definition of bincount "Count number of occurrences of each value in array of non-negative ints." - but I ask for real numbers (-inf, inf) range or just floats

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. Maybe class Counter from collections try: from collections import Counter;
Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0]